# "the" is necessary or not when refering to a paper with reference number

Tags: articles, definite-article

In sentences similar to the one below, is it necessary to put "the" before "paper"?

> This is described in **(the)** paper [8]

Comment: Style guides specify citation formats. These rules vary. They are arbitrary. Such questions are not related to the English language per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Paper [8]** refers to one specific paper, that is its name.  In Khan's example, Room 105 refers to a single, specific room, named "Room 105."  When an object has a specific name in this way, it doesn't need an article.

To be clear, these names aren't always capitalized in the way that I did here.  Another place where this can be confusing is with objects (buildings in particular) that include the word "The" as part of their title, either officially or by custom (ex: "The Fred F. French Building" or "The Hart Senate Office Building")

Examples:

> The meeting is in *conference room B.*
>   I went to the top of *Sears Tower*.
>   The Ewoks are in *Episode 6* of Star Wars.
>   I am reading *book 5* of the Hitchhiker's Guide Trilogy.

Comment: OMG, this answer reminded of [Room 222](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_222), a TV show I had forgotten about. Okay, now back to your regularly scheduled answer.

Answer (score 2):

Please turn to page 21 in your book.

You are booked into room 105.

We don't use "the" when we refer to a noun + number.

So "This is described in paper (8)" is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Based on articles I have read in my field, I would probably omit both "the" and "paper," simply writing

> This is described in [8].

The conventions in your field may be different, though.

(Note: this is more of a comment than an answer but I don't have the necessary reputation.)